# How to cover a polygon with triangles

Tags: c#, directx, slimdx

I'm using slimdx in c#, and my problem is a follows:
I have a list of vertices that forms a polygon, in linestrip format, and I need to transform it to a trianglestrip that covers the polygon.
I started with a center-of-mass calculation, however it only covers convex ones, and I need a general solution.
The final result should look smth like this:
[image]

Does anyone happens to know any algorithms for the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: how many triangles can you use?

Comment: How did you ended up with a collection of lone vertices? Shouldn't you create faces at the same time as you create vertices? Considering you have a linestrip, we actually need to know how your lines are listed to know how we could convert that into tris. Beside, you cannot cover this whole shape with a single linestrip... Are you sure it's a linestrip and you are correctly using it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation

Comment: some code would help describe your request

Comment: I'll try to be more specific:  
I have a collection, say an array, which represents vertices of a polygon. I need to re-create the polygon from said vertices, using triangles which fill the polygon. I the image above - find the middle vertex, and form a new collection which represents the same polygon.  
The purpose of this is to fill the polygon with a color, which (as far as I know) cannot be done with a built-in method of slimdx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's ear clipping algorithm that is quite nice for your use case, an example can be found here:

[Ear clipping c#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8238/Polygon-Triangulation-in-C)